# Taylor polynomial around $x=0$ for $\ln(2+x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

For my homework I got this question: explain what is wrong with this statement:
if $f(x)=\ln(2+x)$, then the second-degree taylor polynomial approximating $f(x)$ around $x=0$ has a negative constant term. I proceeded to calculate the second-degree constant term:
$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{2+x} $$
$$ f''(x)=-(2+x)^{-2} $$
$$ f''(0)= -\frac{1}{4}$$

So I got the negative constant term and I cannot figure out what is wrong with the original statement. I must have made a mistake in my calculations, but need help in finding it.

Comment: The Taylor 2nd degree Taylor Series expansion has 3 terms: constant ($0-th$ degree) term, first degree term, and second degree term. You need to look at the constant term. You're focusing on the 2nd degree term right now. $ln(2 + x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2} + ...$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant term is $f(0)=\ln 2>0.$

$\textbf{Update:}$

The series for $f(x)=\ln \, (2+x)$ is
$$f(x)=\underbrace{\ln 2}_\textrm{const. term} + \frac{1}{2} x -\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \cdots.$$

The constant term is the first term and it is positive.

Comment: Not sure why you use log(x) instead of ln(x)?

Comment: You are right.  This question is a calculus question and also asked using the notation $\ln (\cdot)$.  Although $\log(\cdot)$ is not wrong (sometimes means natural logarithm) it could add unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Edited the notation.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your result is correct. The logarithm function strictly increases, but always slower and slower as $x$ grows. The derivative is always positive but less and less, meaning the second order term of the Taylor expansion is always negative.